# Jetty JMX setup for remote access

Tags: linux, java, centos6, jetty, jmx

I am having some issues getting JMX working on Jetty(9.1.3.v20140225), so I have had a read over the Jetty doco on this.

So I have added the following to the jetty.conf

```
# ========================================================
# jetty.conf Configuration for jetty.sh script
# --------------------------------------------------------
# This file is used by the jetty.sh script to provide
# extra configuration arguments for the start.jar command
# created by that script.
#
# Each line in this file becomes an arguement to start.jar
# in addition to those found in the start.ini file
# =======================================================
jetty-logging.xml
jetty-started.xml
etc/jetty.xml
etc/jetty-jmx.xml
etc/jetty-jmx-remote.xml
```

and I added jmx as part of the start.jar --add-to-start command as the doco told me as part of getting Jconsole connected to Jetty

http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/jetty-jconsole.html

```
[mybase]$ java /opt/jetty-dist/start.jar --add-to-start=jmx
INFO: jmx-remote      initialised in ${jetty.base}/start.ini (appended)
INFO: jmx             initialised transitively
```

Granted when I did this, it only added jmx and not jmx-remote, not sure why but I am hoping someone can let me know why.

In saying all of this from the documentation I have read I have covered off what they want to get this going.

http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/jmx-chapter.html

But again what it states is not completely right as far as what I see in the package, hence the reason I have added jetty-jmx-remote in, as that has what the doco is saying should be in jetty-jmx.xml.

In anycase when I fire up Jetty I am seeing in the log file that it is starting

INFO:oejj.ConnectorServer:main: JMX Remote URL: service:jmx:rmi://host:1099/jndi/rmi://host:1099/jmxrmi

I can telnet to 1099 from the server, from my client, I have used nmap just to double check that the port is listen and also seen it in netstat. When I use VisualVM to connect I just get an error.

I have make sure that I have opened up all ports between my network and the location of the Jetty.

Can anyone point me in the right direction to get this going.

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Sorted it, needed to manually add this in into the start.ini

```
--module=jmx-remote
## JMX Configuration
## Enable for an open port accessible by remote machines
jetty.jmxrmihost=localhost
jetty.jmxrmiport=1099
## Strictly speaking you shouldn't need --exec to use this in most environments.
## If this isn't working, make sure you enable --exec as well
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote
```

And updated this in the jetty-jmx.xml.

```
<Call class="java.lang.System" name="setProperty">
    <Arg>java.rmi.server.hostname</Arg>
    <Arg>IP-Address</Arg>
  </Call>
```

Plus did not need to do what I did to the jetty.conf.